# Share variable between angular component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I have a list of items. The user needs to click on one item to open a new site (new component). In the new component, I need the id of the item the user selected to calculate the specific result.

The following code shows the list of items where the user needs to click.

<div class="item-list">

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
<mat-card class="item-container" id="{{item.id}}" [routerLink]="['/', 'subject', subjectID, 'result', item.id]">

<span>{{item.name}}</span>

</mat-card>
</div>

When the user clicks an item, the new component opens correctly. For example the URL looks like localhost:4200/subject/2/result/5
What I want to do is to access the '5' of the URL in the called component. I tried to access it via a subscription of params like:

`this.route.params.subscribe(params) => {       this.itemID = params('item.id');     }   );`

It shows the error *TS2304: Cannot find name 'params'.*
I think it's because I'm using the id as a path and not as a parameter. Do you have any advice for me how I can resolve my problem?

Comment: Can you also share your Route configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried like this?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
   this.id = params['id'];
  });
}
```

But share your route config, please :)

Comment: You helped me a lot! The router config showed me the correct name of the id:  {path: 'subject/:sid/result/:id', component: ItemResultComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}. Sorry if its a bad question but I didn't know where I have to look for the correct name.